# React native web view to save and load the username and password

Tags: android, react-native

I am creating an android app using React Native. I am using the web view to load the website, the website is having a login page to enter the username and password and we are able to login into the website from the login page. Is it possible to save that username and password details on the webpage or somewhere? so that the next time when the user goes to the login page, he can see the username and password details on the page and the user only needs to click on the login button to login into the website.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
export default class Accountscreen extends Component {
render() {

    return (<WebView source={{ uri: '<site_url>/login'}} style={{ marginTop: 24 }} />);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can communicate between WebView and your rect application https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native

For example when the user login the first time you can send this data with `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage` from your website to RN side and save it.

Next time when you open this page and have login data you can inject JS to your page with `injectedJavaScript`